# Conditional Create: must be the only statement in the batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I only want to create this SQL function if the dependent Assembly exists. 
I can do it using dynamic SQL, but it seems messy and I lose syntax checking (in 
management studio). This function's dependency (for various reasons) may or may 
not be available on an individual developers machine, and I don't want to 
interrupt our local "get latest" process with an error if this is the case.

**Is there a better way?**

```
--Attempt 1 (FAILS)
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = 'SQL_CLR_Functions')
BEGIN
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CLR_CharList_Split(@list nvarchar(MAX), @delim nchar(1) = N',')
    RETURNS TABLE (str nvarchar(4000)) AS EXTERNAL NAME SQL_CLR_Functions.[Library.SQL.CLR.Functions].CLR_CharList_Split
END

--Attempt 2 (FAILS)
BEGIN TRY
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CLR_CharList_Split(@list nvarchar(MAX), @delim nchar(1) = N',')
    RETURNS TABLE (str nvarchar(4000)) AS EXTERNAL NAME SQL_CLR_Functions.[Library.SQL.CLR.Functions].CLR_CharList_Split
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

--Attempt 3 (FAILS)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = 'SQL_CLR_Functions')
BEGIN
 GOTO END_CLR;
END
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CLR_CharList_Split(@list nvarchar(MAX), @delim nchar(1) = N',')
RETURNS TABLE (str nvarchar(4000)) AS EXTERNAL NAME SQL_CLR_Functions.[Library.SQL.CLR.Functions].CLR_CharList_Split
GO
END_CLR:

--Attempt 4 (WORKS!!!)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = 'SQL_CLR_Functions')
BEGIN
    EXEC (N'CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CLR_CharList_Split(@list nvarchar(MAX), @delim nchar(1) = N'','')
            RETURNS TABLE (str nvarchar(4000)) AS EXTERNAL NAME SQL_CLR_Functions.[Library.SQL.CLR.Functions].CLR_CharList_Split')
END
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the [`SET NOEXEC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188394.aspx) statement, which controls whether the subsequent statements are executed (`OFF`) or not (`ON`). Use it in conjunction with your `EXISTS` test like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = 'SQL_CLR_Functions')
  SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CLR_CharList_Split(@list nvarchar(MAX), @delim nchar(1) = N',')
RETURNS TABLE (str nvarchar(4000)) AS EXTERNAL NAME SQL_CLR_Functions.[Granite.SQL.CLR.Functions].CLR_CharList_Split
GO
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

Comment: That's fantastic! Never knew about Set NoExec.